# Ruby-on-Rails: Devise reset-password stopped working, where is the source for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, passwords, reset

I'm trying to fix a website that's implemented using Ruby-on-Rails, which uses Devise for the authentication. I noticed the "Send me reset password instructions" button does not seem to do anything. Or at least, if it's sending out an email - I"m not getting it. I found one Q on SO about this, and it lists source-code from Devise (Devise::PasswordsController): but I did a search of this project and don't see any Devise course-code!

So my question is: Is Devise something that you have to download the source-code for, and build it - in order to have access to the source for debugging it? Or, is the source likely to be hidden away somewhere?

My platform is Ubuntu x64, using devise 3.0.3, and rails 3.2.13.

Thank your for any help, jh.

Answer (score 0):

**Devise** is a typical **Rails Engine**, it is mounted in a Gem-way. No making and building.

Github link to Devise::PasswordsController:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb

In your application, take a look at file **app/views/devise/shared/_links.html.haml** Maybe links are there.

Comment: Thank you Vitalyp, I do see _links.erb, but I still can't find code that handles the reset-password functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can find where the gem is located on your machine using

```
bundle show devise
```

assuming you're using bundler.

If you want you can insert debugger statements in the code in the location it gives to try and see what's going on. Maybe in the passwords controller like Vitalyp suggested.

You can also unpack the source and browse that separately using

```
gem unpack devise
```

which will create a devise-3.0.3 folder from where you run that command. You can specify a location if you want using --target=DIR as an argument.

Comment: Thank you dano, yes - that did point me to where the devise code is, and thus I found passwords_controller.rb  But I can't make out what code is supposed to execute for resetting the password. It does contain protected methods after_resetting_password_path_for, and after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for.  ???